# winjs: implenting rate and review in windows store apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I created the `button` in `appbar` for `Rate and Review` option. I made my javascript as follows;

```
document.getElementById("rate").addEventListener("click", function () { 
"ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=[my-package-name]"
});
```

But, it doesn't navigate to the rate and review page. I know once the app is downloaded from the store only, we can rate and review the app. But, i need to know is my code right ?

will it work once i uploaded it into store ?

Comment: may be try for an existing app in the store based on ms-windows-store url given in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/84932592-0881-45cf-bfc7-57c5460ca83d/windows-rt-and-launching-other-applications)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be solving your problem:

```
    document.getElementById("rate").addEventListener("click", function () { 
                        var uriToLaunch = "ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=your-package-name";
                        var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriToLaunch);
                        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
                        options.treatAsUntrusted = true;
                        Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri, options).then(
                            function (success) {
                                if (success) {
                                } else {
                            }
                        });
     });
```

Comment: thank u so much. if i clicked the button, it opens the store. still i didn't uploaded it in to store. it shows home page of store.